# How to add a table/grid to a vb.net/C# WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I have an asynchronous server listening for clients on a local network. As each client sends a connect message to the server, I want the server to display the client's name in a table.

Assume that I already have the client's name and IP address as a string ClientDetails separated by a _ e.g. "PC5_192.168.1.10"

****EDIT ****

**What I want**

As clients join in, I would like to add each client as a new row to the table/grid.

I am using WPF. Either vb.net or C# answer will be fine, I can translate it myself.

Comment: 1 - If you're using WPF. Tag your question WPF. 2 - Please don't call a WPF `Window` a "form". That's an insult to my beliefs and values. 3 - a `DataGrid` has nothing to do with a Database.

Comment: @HighCore Thumbs up for your comment! :)

Comment: I called it "window" now to help lower your bloodpressure

Comment: @IateaBug_and_iLiked_it you should use MVVM for this. please post a screenshot of what you need and we can give you a way to implement it. For example, a view like the Windows Explorer's "large icons" is just an ItemsControl with a proper DataTemplate and a WrapPanel as its ItemsPanel.

Comment: @HighCore uhm...yes I could... but maybe for now i can be happy with just being able to add the client to my table.

Comment: @IAteABug_And_ILiked_It create a proper `Model` to hold your data and bind the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` property to an `ObservableCollection` of your data items, don't manipulate UI elements in code. Also, make sure you dispatch all modifications to the `ObservableCollection` to the UI Thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Prepared a small example of "the WPF way" to do this.
It looks like this in my computer:

[image]

Im using random values as the data source:

```
 public class RandomConnectionAdder
    {
        public Timer timer;
        public Random random = new Random();

        public Action<Connection> OnConnectionAdded { get; set; }

        public RandomConnectionAdder(Action<Connection> onConnectionAdded)
        {
            OnConnectionAdded = onConnectionAdded;
            timer = new Timer(x => AddConnection(), null, 5000, 2000);
        }

        private void AddConnection()
        {
            var computernumber = random.Next(1, 50);
            var newrandomconnection = new Connection()
                {
                    ComputerName = "PC" + computernumber.ToString(), 
                    IPAddress = "192.168.1." + computernumber,
                    ConnectionTime = DateTime.Now
                };

            if (OnConnectionAdded != null)
                OnConnectionAdded(newrandomconnection);
        }
    }
```

Notice that I added a level of indirection via the use of the `Action<Connection>` delegate to keep the separation of concerns. The "listener" has the responsibility of listening for incoming connections, what to do when a new connection is added is outside its scope.

This is the Model class:

```
  public class Connection: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _computerName;
        public string ComputerName
        {
            get { return _computerName; }
            set
            {
                _computerName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ComputerName");
            }
        }

        private string _ipAddress;
        public string IPAddress
        {
            get { return _ipAddress; }
            set
            {
                _ipAddress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IPAddress");
            }
        }

        private DateTime _connectionTime;
        public DateTime ConnectionTime
        {
            get { return _connectionTime; }
            set
            {
                _connectionTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ConnectionTime");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

This is the Window Code-behind:

```
 public partial class Window6 : Window
    {
        private RandomConnectionAdder adder;
        private ObservableCollection<Connection> Connections;

        public Window6()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Connections = new ObservableCollection<Connection>();
            adder = new RandomConnectionAdder(x => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => AddConnection(x))));
            DataContext = Connections;
        }

        private void AddConnection(Connection connection)
        {
            Connections.Add(connection);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the window instantiates the `RandomConnectionAdder` and sets its `OnConnectionAdded` action to a lambda that dispatches the addition of the item to the `ObservableCollection` to the UI Thread via the `Dispatcher`.

Finally, this is the whole XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.Window6"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window6" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <GroupBox Header="DataGrid">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Computer Name" Binding="{Binding ComputerName}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP Address" Binding="{Binding IPAddress}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Connection Time" Binding="{Binding ConnectionTime, StringFormat='HH:mm:ss'}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Large Icons (ListBox)" Grid.Column="1">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListBox.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ListBox.Template>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel Margin="5" Width="120">
                            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ComputerName}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IPAddress}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConnectionTime, StringFormat='HH:mm:ss'}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Border Height="60" Width="60" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                <TextBlock Text="Some Icon" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Tiles (ListBox)" Grid.Column="2">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListBox.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ListBox.Template>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel Margin="5" Width="120">
                            <Border Height="40" Width="50" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                                <TextBlock Text="Some Icon" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ComputerName}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IPAddress}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConnectionTime, StringFormat='HH:mm:ss'}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>
        </GroupBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see, Im in no way manipulating UI elements in code. This keeps the code clean and easy and well separated, as the Application logic / Data is in no way dependant on the state of UI elements.

Also, in this example can be seen the concept of "Binding several different Views to the Same ViewModel", which in this case is the `ObservableCollection` itself.

This is "the WPF" approach for everything. You almost never have to manipulate UI elements in code, at least not in regards to application logic or data.

Just copy and paste my code in a `File -> New Project -> WPF Application` and see the results for yourself.

Comment: woh! thats a verrrrry detailed answer ! A++ .. I shall try this then.